# How can i change JMS_IBM_MQMD_Format: MQHRF2 to JMS_IBM_MQMD_Format: MQSTR?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

How can i change **JMS_IBM_MQMD_Format: MQHRF2** to **JMS_IBM_MQMD_Format: MQSTR** in WebsphereMQ Message?

I need JMS_IBM_MQMD_Format: MQSTR

i got output like:

```
JMSMessage class: jms_text
  JMSType:          null
  JMSDeliveryMode:  2
  JMSExpiration:    0
  JMSPriority:      4
  JMSMessageID:     ID:010203040506070801020304050607080102030405060708
  JMSTimestamp:     1365655482749
  JMSCorrelationID: null
  JMSDestination:   queue:///MYQUEUE?mdMessageContext=1&mdWriteEnabled=true
  JMSReplyTo:       null
  JMSRedelivered:   false
    JMSXAppID: WebSphere MQ Client for Java
    JMSXDeliveryCount: 1
    JMSXUserID:             
    JMS_IBM_Character_Set: UTF-8
    JMS_IBM_Encoding: 273
    JMS_IBM_Format: MQSTR   
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_AccountingToken: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_ApplIdentityData:                                 
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_ApplOriginData:     
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_BackoutCount: 0
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_CodedCharSetId: 1208
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_CorrelId: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_Encoding: 273
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_Expiry: -1
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_Feedback: 0
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_Format: MQHRF2  
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_GroupId: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgFlags: 0
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgId: 010203040506070801020304050607080102030405060708
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgSeqNumber: 1
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgType: 8
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_Offset: 0
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_OriginalLength: -1
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_Persistence: 1
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_Priority: 4
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_PutApplName: WebSphere MQ Client for Java
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_PutApplType: 28
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_PutDate: 20130411
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_PutTime: 04444315
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_ReplyToQ:                                                 
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_ReplyToQMgr: MYQM                                            
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_Report: 0
    JMS_IBM_MQMD_UserIdentifier:             
    JMS_IBM_MsgType: 8
    JMS_IBM_PutApplType: 28
    JMS_IBM_PutDate: 20130411
    JMS_IBM_PutTime: 04444315
```

SimpleMQMDWrite: Your lucky number today is 733

Answer (score 1):

```
Destination producerDestination = producerSession.createQueue(
    messagingQueueDetail.getRequestQueueName()
);

((MQQueue) producerDestination).setTargetClient(JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);

// MessageProducer is used for sending messages
producer = producerSession.createProducer(producerDestination);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the code does and/or why this solves the question.

Comment: The setTargetClient method controls if the RFH2 should be included. See https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/msg/client/wmq/common/CommonConstants.html#WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ and https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/msg/client/wmq/common/CommonConstants.html#WMQ_CLIENT_JMS_COMPLIANT

Answer (score 0):

In your `MessageCreator` implementation (class that implements `MessageCreator`) add a `setJMSType` with the value `"MQSTR"`:

```java
public TextMessage createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
    TextMessage messageObject = session.createTextMessage();
    messageObject.setText(message);
    messageObject.setJMSType("MQSTR");
    return messageObject;
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tested this?